# Determine Oracle query execution time and proposed datasize without actually executing query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

In oracle Is there any way to determine howlong the sql query will take to fetch the entire records and what will be the size of it, Without actually executing and waiting for entire result.

I am getting repeatedly to download and provide the data to the users using normal oracle SQL select (not datapump/import etc) . Some times rows will be in millions.

Comment: If your statistics are up to date, the [execution plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601) will show you an estimation of the number of rows.

Comment: but how to get the howlong the query will run and size of data going to retrieve

Comment: The execution plan not only includes the number of rows but also the size of the data. It also includes an ***approximate*** estimate of the run time - but I have *never* seen that to be anywhere near the actual runtimes.

Comment: if you have plsql then paste the query in sql window and hit f5, it will display your execution plan , you can see the cost of the query and the others details regarding records

Comment: @anudeepks "*if you have plsql*" doesn't make sense. PL/SQL is a programming language. You can't paste anything "into" a programming language

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, actually meant, plsql developer.

Answer (score 2):

Actual run time will not known unless you run it, but you can try to estimate it..

1. first you can do **explain plan** explain only, this will **NOT** run query -- based on your current stats it will show you more or less how it will be executed
2. this will not have actual time and efforts to read the data from datablocks..
3. do you have large blocksize
4. is this schema normalized/de-normalized for query/reporting?
5. how large is row does it fit in same block so only 1 fetch is needed?
6. ## of rows you are expecting
7. based on amount of data * your network latency

Based on this you can try estimate time

Answer (score 2):

This requires good statistics, `explain plan for ...`, adjusting `sys.aux_stats`, and then adjusting your expectations.

---

1. **Good statistics** The explain plan estimates are based on optimizer statistics.  Make sure that tables and indexes have up-to-date statistics.  On 11g this usually means sticking with the default settings and tasks, and only manually gathering statistics after large data loads.
2. **`Explain plan for ...`**  Use a statement like this to create and store the explain plan for any SQL statement.  This even works for creating indexes and tables.

   ```
   explain plan set statement_id = 'SOME_UNIQUE_STRING' for
   select * from dba_tables cross join dba_tables;
   ```

   This is usually the best way to visualize an explain plan:

   ```
   select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);


   Plan hash value: 2788227900

   -------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Id  | Operation              | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Time     |
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |       |    12M|  5452M| 00:00:19 |
   |*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER |       |    12M|  5452M| 00:00:19 |
   |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | SEG$  |  7116 |   319K| 00:00:01 |
   ...
   ```

   The raw data is stored in `PLAN_TABLE`.  The first row of the plan usually  sums up the estimates for the other steps:

   ```
   select cardinality, bytes, time
   from plan_table
   where statement_id = 'SOME_UNIQUE_STRING'
       and id = 0;

   CARDINALITY    BYTES         TIME
   12934699       5717136958    19
   ```
3. **Adjust sys.aux_stats$**  The time estimate is based on system statistics stored in `sys.aux_stats`.  These are numbers for metrics like CPU speed, single-block I/O read time, etc.  For example, on my system:

   ```
   select * from sys.aux_stats$ order by sname

   SNAME            PNAME         PVAL1              PVAL2
   SYSSTATS_INFO    DSTART                           09-11-2014 11:18
   SYSSTATS_INFO    DSTOP                            09-11-2014 11:18
   SYSSTATS_INFO    FLAGS                        1    
   SYSSTATS_INFO    STATUS                           COMPLETED
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    CPUSPEED
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    CPUSPEEDNW    3201.10192837466    
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    IOSEEKTIM                   10    
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    IOTFRSPEED                4096    
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    MAXTHR
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    MBRC
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    MREADTIM
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    SLAVETHR
   SYSSTATS_MAIN    SREADTIM
   ```

   The numbers can be are automatically gathered by `dbms_stats.gather_system_stats`.  They can also be manually modified.  It's a SYS table but relatively safe to modify.  Create some sample queries, compare the estimated time with the actual time, and adjust the numbers until they match.
4. **Discover you probably wasted a lot of time**

   Predicting run time is theoretically impossible to get right in all cases, and in practice it is horribly difficult to forecast for non-trivial queries.  Jonathan Lewis wrote a whole [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596366) about those predictions, and that book only covers the "basics".

   Complex explain plans are typically "good enough" if the estimates are off by one or two orders of magnitude.  But that kind of difference is typically not good enough to show to a user, or use for making any important decisions.