# How find the time required to creating a table?

Tags: oracle

I want to know how much time is required to create a table i oracle??
if there is any views to find out the details or any other operation to get more statistical information about the query running of create table?

Comment: Do you mean a simple "create table" statement, showing column names, data types and constraints? Or "create table as select ..." where the "select" part may take a long time?

Comment: What's your motivation for the question ? I have never thought table creation time to be an issue. In practice a table is created "immediately". If you've a scenario where you are going to create tables dynamically at run-time you should very like reconsider your design.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29940412/409172  If you're running a large Create Table As SQL (CTAS), then `explain plan` would be the best way to estimate the run time.  If you're creating a table with a SQL statement, then the time should be so small it's not worth measuring.

Comment: Data base performance deals with SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE on tables with lots of rows. How often do you create an empty table? How many INSERTs are needed to get a lot of rows?